# How do we know that $\{x: x\text{ is a set and }x\text{ has at least one element}\}$ has any elements at all?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been going through introductory set theory notes and came across the following.

First, it is possible for a set to be an element of itself. An example of a set which is an element of itself is
$$A =\{x: x\text{ is a set and }x\text{ has at least one element}\}$$
This set contains itself, because it is a set with at least one element.

How do we know the set $A$ has at least one element? Could someone help understand this

Comment: $A$ doesn't look like a set to me. Either way for example $\{\emptyset\} \in A$.

Comment: For people who wonder about the context: This seems to be from a note on Russel's Paradox, and a bit further above we read: "At this time (around 1900), it was generally believed that any property of objects could definea set."
https://math.berkeley.edu/~kpmann/Russell.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A$ contains the set $\{\varnothing\}$, so it has at least one element and thereby contains itself.

However, note that $A$ is defined by an unrestricted comprehension, which is not allowed in ZFC. It becomes a *proper class*.

Comment: Ohk.. I'm wondering if there is anything special about $\{\varnothing\}$? Can I just convince myself with a different set. Ex: $B = \{1\} \in A$ ? because $B$ is also a set with one element, so it satisfies the condition to belong in $A$ ?

Comment: @across $\{\varnothing\}$ is something we can construct out of the axioms alone. No need to define the natural numbers this way.